# How to check for directshow filters on pc

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

Is there a way to see what filter's are installed on my machine, because i have a C# winform application that takes a photo using directshow that works perfectly fine on my laptop but won't work on my desktop.

On my desktop it says "No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection", so is there a way to copy over the filters or see which filters are used?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was installing windows 7 ultimate, as the new machine only had starter on it and for some reason it is really useless....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) to visually build a graph and see which filters are used.